# CakePHP - Psr classes not found

Tags: php, cakephp, psr-7

I have the following errors:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface' not found in /home/www/forex-arts/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php on line 37
>
> Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface' not found in /home/www/forex-arts/vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/Uri.php on line 25

I am using CakePHP.  Does anyone know why I am receiving these errors?

Comment: Hello.  Can you please provide context for this question?  Showing errors without *any* code at all is going to make it difficult for someone to help you.  However, I can tell you now that you need to import the PSR-7 HTTP Message Interface library.

Comment: thanks in advance Jason Roman ,i already installed plugins for that before :"guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.4",
   "psr/http-message": "^1.0",

Comment: Not sure then - I'd do a composer update and check your /vendor/ directory